# Centering a container view

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, ios-autolayout, visual-format-language

//I have 3 containers in the screen. Top/ middle / bottom (i've added just middle's codes here)

```
- (void)initLayoutConstrains
{
[self initMiddleLayoutContainerConstraint];
NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =     NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_topContainerBar, _bottomContainerBar, _middleContainerBar);
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(>=20)-[_middleContainerBar(==200)]-(>=20)-|"
                                                               options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: i have not much time but here is a temporary solution i came up with:

```
CGFloat testViewHeight = 200;
NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"testViewY": @(self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - testViewHeight / 2), @"testViewHeight":@(testViewHeight)};

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-testViewY-[testView(==testViewHeight)]"
                                                                         options: kNilOptions
                                                                         metrics:metrics
                                                                           views:viewsDictionary]];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[testView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: sorry i've changed it. can you take a look again?

Comment: how can we do it universal i mean with this its just showing right on ipad not iphones ?

Comment: self.view.frame.size.height / 2 should be the middle of the screen for both iphone and ipad. i created my code in iphone btw

Comment: Thank you :) just one last question. how can i move this button to the right when its in the middle.

Comment: [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[testView(==100)]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]]; should work, for example. notice that i did not put the | character to the left, and i set the width

Comment: Thank you so much for all your explanation. Its working perfectly.